# Can't start mysql after moving to external drive

Tags: mysql, centos7

Earlier this month I inherited a MySQL Server 5.6 hosted on a minute Azure VM with a single 30GB HDD. The Database was consuming 22GB; disk usage was at 89%.

#### Migrate /var/lib/mysql to mounted disk with symlink

```
lsblk && df
sudo mkdir /media/sdc
fdisk /dev/sdc
     n p 1 2048 209715199 w
sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdc1
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/sdc
sudo systemctl stop mysqld
sudo cp -dpR /var/lib/mysql /media/sdc/mysql
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.old
sudo ln -s /media/sdc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```

I mounted an external drive, migrated the database files to the external drive; afterwards, and changed the original mysql directory into a symlink pointing to the new location. Initially I thought it may be a reference problem with mysql not traversing the symlink. So I changed my tactic to mount the external drive directly to /var/lib/mysql.

## Mount disk to /var/lib/mysql and migrate data.

```
#Remove the migrated files (I still have mysql.old)
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -R /media/sdc/mysql

#Mount the drive to /var/lib/mysql directly.
sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /var/lib/mysql
sudo cp -dpR /var/lib/mysql.old /var/lib/mysql
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

This didn't work either. In both cases, mysql refuses to start for the same reasons:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
Job for mysqld.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

#### `systemctl status mysqld.service`

```
systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Community Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: activating (start-post) since Tue 2017-07-18 20:58:12 UTC; 4min 37s ago
Process: 32798 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 32787 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 32798 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS); : 32799 (mysql-systemd-s)
CGroup: /system.slice/mysqld.service
└─control
├─32799 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysql-systemd-start post
└─33965 sleep 1
```

#### `journalctl -xe`

```
~
…
~
...skipping...
~
…
~
```

Additionally, I also tried various methods to start the server to no avail (same results):

```
sudo systemctl start mysqld
sudo systemctl start mysql.service
sudo systemctl start mysql
service mysql restart
```

#### `ps aux | grep mysql`

```
admin_u+ 58206  0.0  0.0 112648   976 pts/0    R+   14:19   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

## How do I resolve this issue and start mysql?

Did I overlook something? I thought it may also be the datadir setting as in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/798897/mysql-wont-start-with-datadir-change); but, both methods I took does not modify the datadir path...

Comment: Look in MySQL's log.  That's where you usually find the reason MySQL can't start.

Comment: How many MYSQL instances is running `ps aux | grep mysql`? Is selinux enabled?

Comment: According to ps aux:  1 instance. running system ctl stop mysqd, mysql.service, and mysql didn't close the process. See my edit for the full output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoonix suggested I look at the MySQL Log.

#### `mysqld.log`

```
...
017-07-19 13:45:13 0 [Note] Binlog end
170719 13:45:13 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
170719 13:55:13 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2017-07-19 13:55:13 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
2017-07-19 13:55:13 0 [ERROR] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
2017-07-19 13:55:13 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

## Solution:

When mounting the drive and moving files over to the external drive, I had also moved mysql-files too. Upon moving it back, I failed to rename it back to **`/mysql-files`**. Instead I renamed it to **`/mysqlfiles`**. Renaming the directory fixed the issue.